# Can anyone suggest how to also include work hours (9-5) in this out-of-office script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-filters, gmail-canned-response

The below script successfully auto-replies to sender on selected non-working-days.
Can anyone suggest how I might add the after-hours of working-days, say 5pm-7am, to trigger the reply also?

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;        //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [1,5,6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoresponded");
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox !label:autoresponded after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (message.getFrom().indexOf("myemail@gmail.com") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("no-repl") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("bounce") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("spam") < 0) {
        threads[i].reply("", {
          htmlBody: "<p>Thank you for your message. I am not in the office today. If you have urgent questions you can email office@example.com. If you have other urgent enquiries you can call the office on 1800 999 002.</p><p>Best regards,<br>Name</p>"
        });
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Your title and opening sentance aren't consistent. Just to clarify... The script currently sends an out-of-office reply to all emails received on Monday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday (days off). Your question is how do you modify the script so that it also sends an out-of-office reply to all emails received between 5pm and 7pm (after hours) on Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday (working hours). Is that an accurate summary?

Comment: Apologies, you’re right - I’ve posted the above script including Monday and Friday accidentally after some fiddling. My intention is to auto reply after-hours during the work week and at all hours across the weekend.

Comment: Good, my answer takes this into account. Define `daysOff` however you wish; maybe just `var daysOff = [6,0];`. `daysOff.indexOf(day)` will return the index if the current day is a weekend, satisfying `(daysOff.indexOf(day) !=-1)`. If the current day is NOT a weekend **AND** if the time is after 5pm and before 7pm (i.e. after-hours on a weekday), then the result will satisfy `(daysOff.indexOf(day) ==-1 && currenthour >=starthour && currenthour<=endhour)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send a message after-hours on working days as well as on days-off.

Adjust your script for the following:

- Add variables for 'currenthour', 'starthour' and 'endhour'

---

```
 var date = new Date();    
 var day = date.getDay();    
 // get the current hour    
 var currenthour = date.getHours();    
 // define the after-hours start and end hours    
 var starthour= 17;    
 var endhour = 19;
```

- Then modify your `IF` statement

`if ((daysOff.indexOf(day) !=-1) ||(daysOff.indexOf(day) ==-1 && currenthour >=starthour && currenthour<=endhour)) {`

The variables return the current date and enable a "between" calculation to be done.
The IF statement will execute if either

- `indexOf(day) !=-1`: that is, if it is a work day

OR

- `indexOf(day) ==-1`: that it IS a working day, AND the current time is during after-hours

Comment: Ahh! Awesome - that's got me sorted... I'll post my altered version below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - I've combined your inputs :)

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;        //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
 var date = new Date();    
 var day = date.getDay();    
 // get the current hour    
 var currenthour = date.getHours();    
 // define the work-hours start and end hours    
 var starthour= 7;    
 var endhour = 17; 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoresponded");
if ((daysOff.indexOf(day) !=-1) ||(daysOff.indexOf(day) ==-1 && !(currenthour >=starthour && currenthour <=endhour))) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox label:myfilteringlabel !label:autoresponded after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (message.getFrom().indexOf("myemail@gmail.com") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("no-repl") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("bounce") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("spam") < 0) {
        threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: "<p>blah blah</p>", from: 'user@email.com', name: 'User'});}
          
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I just need to learn how to call a variable of the sender's name and embed in the body :/

Comment: I realise that this represents the successful combination of your code and my input but it's not an answer, per se. It's the result of applying an answer to your code. You might/should include this revised script at the end of your question (under a suitable heading) so that others can see the entire script and benefit from it in the future. Once you've done that, you should delete this answer.